# Fourier series of $|A\sin(wt)|$

Tags: fourier-series

I am having some trouble calculating the fourier series of $x(t)=|A\sin(wt)|$. 
I have thought that the period is $T'=\frac{T}{2}=\frac{\pi}{w}$ so the result that i ended up was $c[n]=\dfrac{-A}{\pi} \dfrac{(-1)^n+1}{(n+1)(n-1)}$ but i thing it's wrong. I tried ploting $x(t)$ using this $c[n]$ in Matlab for $n=25$, $50$ or $100$ but the results were "correct" only when i ploted using plot(A-abs(x)), otherwise there were upside down. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is this number you're calling $T$?  The period of $t\mapsto A\sin(wt)$ is $2\pi/w$, and the period of $t\mapsto|A\sin(wt)|$ is $\pi/w$.

Comment: the period $T=pi/w$.

Comment: Is there any change you saw $\sin(\omega t)$ and copied it as $\sin(wt)$?  In some fields, notably electrical engineering, the letter $\omega$ is often used for frequency.

Comment: In this case the letter $w$ stands for angular frequency. For frequency i prefer to use $f$.

Comment: @BillSkiadas Michael's point is that the letter "double u" is not the same as the letter "omega", that is, $w\neq\omega$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the tip. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up some factors of $2$: check the formula for [cosine series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierCosineSeries.html).

I get the series 
$$\frac{2|A|}{\pi} -\frac{4|A|}{\pi} \sum_{n\ge 2, \text{ even}} \frac{1}{n^2-1}\cos nwt$$
With $A=1$ and $w=1$, the partial sum computed in Sage with

```
2/pi+sum([-4/(pi*((2*k)^2-1))*cos(2*k*x) for k in range(1,5)])
```

matched the function pretty well:

[image: partial]

Comment: why n>2 even must be even?

Comment: @BillSkiadas There is $(-1)^n+1$ in the formula for $c_n$. This is zero when $n$ is odd, and $2$ when $n$ is even. I decided to save the computer the trouble of multiplying things by zero. This is why I replaced $n$ with $2k$ in my Sage command.